# How to set class for react component with state?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I am trying to make it so that when I click on a button the class of a component changes, allowing for different styling to be applied. I keep getting an error of infinite rendering but I don't know whats wrong.  Here is my code.

````
const Nav2 = () => {
    const [activeLinks, setActiveLinks] = useState(true);
    const [activeIcons, setActiveIcons] = useState(true);

    const toggleMenu = () => {
        if (activeLinks === true) {
            setActiveLinks(false);
        } else if (activeLinks === false) {
            setActiveLinks(true);
        }
        if (activeIcons === true) {
            setActiveIcons(false);
        } else if (activeIcons === false) {
            setActiveIcons(true);
        }
    }

    return (
        <nav id="lined-nav">
            <div className="logo">Umar Manzoor</div>
            <div className="lined-menu">
                <div className={activeIcons ? "lined-icon" : "lined-icon open"} onClick={toggleMenu()}>
                    <span></span>
                    <span></span>
                    <span></span>
                </div>
                <div className={activeLinks ? "menu-links" : "menu-links open"}>
                    <li><a href="#about" onClick={toggleMenu()}>About</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#experience" onClick={toggleMenu()}>Experience</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#projects" onClick={toggleMenu()}>Projects</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#contact" onClick={toggleMenu()}>Contact</a></li>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
    )
}

export default Nav2```
````

Comment: All those `onClick={toggleMenu()}`s need to be `onClick={toggleMenu}`.

Comment: Also: `setActiveLinks(value => !value);` (ditto for `setActiveIcons`). No need for `if`s.

Answer (score 2):

The issue is how you're calling the methods. When you do `onClick={toggleMenu()}` you're basically running the methods once, which re-renders the view, which then makes the functions trigger again and so on.

What you should do is, since your functions are actually constants, either do `onClick={toggleMenu}` or, you can also do (which also works with functions and you can add parameters), `onClick={() => toggleMenu()}`.